# Print openCV Mat content with certain format in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to ask how to format a OpenCV Mat in C++ and print it out?

For example, a Mat with double content M, when I wrote

```
cout<<M<<endl;
```

I will get

```
[-7.7898273846583732e-15, -0.03749374753019832; -0.0374787251930463, -7.7893623846343843e-15]
```

But I want a neat output, for example

```
[0.0000, -0.0374; -0.0374, 0.0000]
```

Is there any built-in way to do so?

I know we can use

```
cout<<format(M,"C")<<endl;
```

to set the output styple. So I am looking for something similar to this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Exact duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992370/cvmat-matrix-how-to-reduce-digits-to-the-right-of-the-decimal-point-in-cvma

Comment: Thanks! I searched a few minutes but did not find any related question so I posted. It was a problem of different choices of keywords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv::Mat matrix, HOW TO Reduce digits to the right of the decimal point in cv::Mat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992370/cvmat-matrix-how-to-reduce-digits-to-the-right-of-the-decimal-point-in-cvma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void print(Mat mat, int prec)
{      
    for(int i=0; i<mat.size().height; i++)
    {
        cout << "[";
        for(int j=0; j<mat.size().width; j++)
        {
            cout << setprecision(prec) << mat.at<double>(i,j);
            if(j != mat.size().width-1)
                cout << ", ";
            else
                cout << "]" << endl; 
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double data[2][4];
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = 0.123456789;
        }
    }
    Mat src = Mat(2, 4, CV_64F, &data);
    print(src, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

new versions of OpenCV make it easy!

see [cv::Formatter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/da1/classcv_1_1Formatter.html)

```
Mat src;
...
cv::Ptr<cv::Formatter> fmt = cv::Formatter::get(cv::Formatter::FMT_DEFAULT);
fmt->set64fPrecision(4);
fmt->set32fPrecision(4);
std::cout << fmt->format(src) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
cout.precision(5);
cout << M << endl;
```

You may also want to set the format to fixed before:

```
cout.setf( std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield );
```

Comment: Thank you! I added this setf command first, and then precision command second. The format did changed (now -7.7898273846583732e-15 becomes 0.00000000000000). But it is still too long.

Comment: Then the implementation of the printing-method of the matrix overwrites the precision.

Comment: @Marius To set the precision with the builtin opencv `mat::operator<<` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40672924/15485